# No View found for id : Call fragment from AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, fragment, android-framelayout

I am very new to android and currently working on a project in which I have to open a Fragment from activity class. 
I am using appCompat activity as AlertDialog and on click of Ok button I want to open a Fragment in Framelayout.
But unfortunately I am getting error that No view found for id for fragment:

AlertDriver Activity:

```
public class AlertDriver extends AppCompatActivity {
MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alertdialog);
    Log.e("EyeSens", "Inside AlertDriver - onCreate");

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wakeup);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("SafeSnooze alert: ");
    // set dialog message
    alertDialog
            .setMessage("Sleepy? Go to the nearby rest areas.")
            //.setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    stopService(getIntent());
                    //release mp3
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                    try {
                        Log.e("EyeSens", "Cancel pressed - Starting camera 
again");
                        if (!isCameraRunning) {
                            //Initializing EyeTracking Constructor
                            new EyeTracking();
                            //noinspection MissingPermission
                            mCameraSource.start();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    dialog.cancel();
                    finish();

                }
            }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            //release mp3
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();

            // if this button is clicked, just close
            // the dialog box and do nothing
            Log.e("EyeSens", "Ok pressed - Starting 
LocationCategoriesFragment");
            try {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
//                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, new 
LocationCategoriesFragment(), "AlertLocation");
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new 
LocationCategoriesFragment());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("EyeSens", "Exception thrown: "+e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            stopService(getIntent());
            dialog.cancel();
            finish();
        }
    });
```

LocationCategoriesFragment Fragment:

```
public class LocationCategoriesFragment extends Fragment {
public static String REQUEST_URL = "";
public ArrayList<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<Category> catData = new ArrayList<>();
public ListView categoriesLV = null;
public TextView error;

public LocationCategoriesFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location_categories, 
container, false);
    categoriesLV = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    final GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) 
getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    globalVariable.setLocation(false);
    //categories = fetchCategories(categoriesLV);
    return view;
}
}
```

Manifest file Configuration:

```
....
      <activity
          android:name=".util.AlertDriver"
          android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert"/>
```

app_bar_navigation.xml Framelayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.kumarhar.eyerecog.Navigation">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0f00e2 (com.example.kumarhar.eyerecog:id/fragment_container) for fragment LocationCategoriesFragment{2e9a6264 #0 id=0x7f0f00e2 AlertLocation}
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1293)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
```

alertdialog.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
 </LinearLayout>
```

Note: I want to open LocationCategoriesFragment fragment from AlertDriver AppCompatActivity through setPositiveButton listener.

Please help..

Comment: `setContentView(R.layout.alertdialog);` you set this as layout, but show XML of `app_bar_navigation.xml`. Why?

Comment: @VladMatvienko AlertDriver activity class is using alertdialog layout and its creating the alert dynamically. And app_bar_navigation has the framelayout in which fragment needs to be replaced.

Comment: but you don;t use `app_bar_navigation`, and try to set the fragment into Activity, that uses `R.layout.alertdialog`, which does not have `fragment_container`

Comment: @VladMatvienko problem is solved. As suggested by you i have called the app_bar_navigation first and then called the fragments and it works fine. Thanks for the support.